# How to extract apache2 mod-status information for logging and performance metrics

Tags: performance, apache2, metrics

The server-status page give good information. But I am looking for a way to have the information extracted into a loggable/metric fashion. For example memory usage and cpu load per request would be very interesting to include in a dashboard or report on cpu heavy pages.

Is there a way to extract that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be difficult to break information down to a specific page, though you can retrieve and log that data from within a script that you may be running in PHP/Ruby/Python/etc and log it.

For more general Apache stats, you can append `?auto` to get a more machine-readable version of the server-status.

```
http://example.com/server-status?auto
```